# Knockoutjs select initial value binding

Tags: knockout.js

I hava the following knockoutjs code. Problem is that i want to be able to set the value of the selectedCountry variable but to do that i have to bind it to the select element as selectedCountry, however in order to get the initial value i have to use this selectedCountry() instead, and am thus not able to update the value of selectedCountry when another option is selected. How do i go about this?

```
The code is also available here http://jsfiddle.net/xPc9J/

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>
    Your country: 
    <select data-bind="options: availableCountries,  optionsValue: 'countryPopulation',optionsText: 'countryName',value: selectedCountry(), optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
</p>
<span data-bind="text: selectedCountry() ? selectedCountry().countryPopulation : 'unknown'"></span>.
<div data-bind="visible: selectedCountry"> <!-- Appears when you select something -->
    You have chosen a country with population 
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry() ? selectedCountry().countryPopulation : 'unknown'"></span>.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Constructor for an object with two properties
    var country = function(name, population) {
        this.countryName = name;
        this.countryPopulation = population;    
    };        
 var sel=new country("USA", 320000000);
    console.log(sel);
    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray([
            new country("UK", 65000000),
            new country("USA", 320000000),
            new country("Sweden", 29000000)
        ]),
        selectedCountry : ko.observable(320000000) // Nothing selected by default
    };
    console.log(viewModel.selectedCountry());
    //viewModel.selectedCountry(sel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectedCountry` property holds the currently selected population not the whole 
`country`.

So instead everywhere where you have `selectedCountry().countryPopulation` you should write
simply `selectedCountry()`:

```
<span data-bind="text: selectedCountry"></span>.
<div data-bind="visible: selectedCountry">
    You have chosen a country with population 
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry() ? selectedCountry(): 'unknown'">
    </span>.
</div>​
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gHukB/).

Note you had an extra set of `()` in your `select`'s `value` binding, so correct syntax is:

`value: selectedCountry`